# Multi-column search performs search only for the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, webgrid

I am using jQuery multifilter plug-in, but the multi column search works good only for the current page, how can I use the same plug-in to search the entire data-table(from other pages as well)?
Kindly help, Thanks.

Multicolumn search using jQuery plugin MultiFilter :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter').multifilter()
    console.log(jQuery().jquery);
})
```

The text-boxes for each column to search :

```
<div class='filter-container'>
    <input autocomplete='off' class='filter txtBox1 ' id="txtB1" name='employeeid' placeholder='Employee Id' data-col='Employee ID' onkeyup="myFunction1()" />
</div>
<div class='filter-container'>
    <input autocomplete='off' class='filter txtBox2 ' id="txtB2" name='firstname' placeholder='First Name' data-col='First Name' />
</div>
<div class='filter-container'>
    <input autocomplete='off' class='filter txtBox3 ' id="txtB3" name='lastname' placeholder='Last Name' data-col='Last Name' />
</div>
<div class='filter-container'>
    <input autocomplete='off' class='filter txtBox4 ' id="txtB4" name='dateofbirth' placeholder='Date of Birth' data-col='Date Of Birth' />
</div>
```

[Search happens only on the particular page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olRnp.png)

Comment: Javascript only knows about what's on the page. This sounds like a problem that needs to be fixed on the db end

Comment: Sanjana V  if you are using data-tables then you can use its each-column-filter functionality. they are providing that facility and it filter record for all pages. check here:- https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: Since I am using WebGrid, I am not able to fully implement DataTable. @AlivetoDie